# How to color part of a fraction e.g. denominator

Tags: manim

```
txt11 = TexMobject(r"-7", color=BLACK)
txt12 = TexMobject(r"\frac{1}{7}", color=BLACK).next_to(txt11, RIGHT)
```

I wanna color the denominator of txt12, tried splitting txt12 to:

```
txt12 = TexMobject(r"\frac{1}", r"{7}", color=BLACK).next_to(txt11, RIGHT)
txt12.set_color_by_tex("{7}", BLUE)
```

but not work, then I create a new txt13 overlapped with txt12 but a null molecular:

```
txt13 = TexMobject(r"\frac{}{7}", color=BLUE).move_to(txt12.get_center())
```

also not work.

Is there feasible way to color part of equation like fraction? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Specifically for a fraction, you can use

```py
TexMobject(r"1", r"\over", r"7").set_color_by_tex("7", BLUE)
```

`set_color_by_tex("7", BLUE)` sets the submobject with text `7` to `BLUE`.

The LaTeX `{a \over b}` command is a shorthand for `\frac{a}{b}`.

This is how Grant Sanderson sometimes do it, for example, in [this recent video](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/blob/e1e66f3082d9ba28b47895b342fc53b6f8e3feda/active_projects/diffyq/part2/heat_equation.py#L1972).